# Ударение в имени Адам (Смит)

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия, ономастика

На какой слог падает ударение в имени известного экономиста? Неужели под влиянием «Евгения Онегина» — на второй слог?

P. S. Википедия не авторитный источник.

Comment: В.Набоков написал «Комментарии к "Евгению Онегину"» и в них прошёлся по многим ударениям в словах и фамилиях. Адаму Смиту там тоже посвящено несколько абзацев, но ничего нет об ударении. Косвенный аргумент.

Answer (score 1):

**Ада́м Смит** (англ. Adam Smith)

http://stuki-druki.com/authors/Smith_Adam.php

Имя Адам древнееврейское имя, дословно означает «созданный из красной глины», позднее это имя стало нарицательным и стало означать «человек». Существуют варианты имени – Эдам, Адем, Адан, а также вариации перевода – «земляной», «красный». **В имени Адам ударение можно поставить, как на первый, так и на последний слог**.

Подробнее на https://kakzovut.ru/names/adam.html

Сравнить: Адамс генри Брукс – американский писатель, ударение на первом слоге.

**Другие источники:**

1) **О словаре  http://udarenie.gramatik.ru/**

Правильное ударение:

Ада́м, -а (также: ве́тхий Ада́м, о человеке); 
Ада́м, (Ада́мович, Ада́мовна)

В словаре представлены не только слова, вызывающие затруднение при постановке ударения, но и вся лексика из «Русского орфографического словаря», который насчитывает более 150 000 слов. Некоторые данные были дополнены информацией из «Орфоэпического словаря русского языка» Розниченко И. Л. Для большинства слов приведены словоформы. Словарь является справочником и приводит нормы написания и постановки ударения на начало 3 тысячателетия. Если вы нашли ошибку или готовы оспорить приведенные данные, то просим писать по адресу coocon@yandex.ru.

**2) http://globuss24.ru/**

Ада́м Смит (англ. Adam Smith); крещён и возможно родился 5 июня (16 июня) 1723, Керколди — 17 июля 1790, Эдинбург) — шотландский экономист, философ-этик; один из основоположников современной экономической теории.

**Вывод:** На русском языке надо говорить по-русски, с ударением на втором слоге, о чем сообщается в любом источнике. 
Ударение на первом слоге характерно для германских языков.

Comment: К сожалению, сайт «Штуки-дрюки», как и Википедия, не приводит надежных источников в подтверждение, поэтому не могу согласиться с предложенным вариантом.

Comment: Как сказано в Книге Бытия, Бог создал Адама из праха земного. Земля, грунт на иврите — *адама*, поэтому Адам. Красный на иврите — *адом*, и скорее всего *адама* и *адом* имеют общий корень, но Адам все же сотворен из земли, а не из красной глины.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, в сторону ударения на втором слоге здесь повлияли ранние традиции транскрипции с английского языка (хотя Смит и шотландец, вряд ли это сказалось на языковом источнике имени). Как известно, в паре со Смитом часто фигурирует Давид Рикардо, современная транскрипция имени которого была бы "Дэвид" (в английском произносится ближе к Дейвид, уменьшительное Дейв). Для старой традиции было типичным адаптировать некоторые иностранные имена к давно используемым в русском языке, например, в одном из советских изданий мне попадалось "*Михаил* Фарадей" (вместо современного *Майкл*) - дополнительно в своё время сказалось его включение в почётные члены Петербургской академии наук. Видимо, традиция приближения к английскому произношению при транскрипции имён, бытовавшая  в середине прошлого века и уже ушедшая (Уотсон -> Ватсон), не повлияла на ударение в имени этого деятеля, активно произносившегося преподавателями марксизма, и оно закрепилось подобно тому, как когда-то раз и навсегда закрепилась транскрипция фамилии Томаса Мора - современных же носителей такой фамилии (Moore) записывают как Мур (напр. актёр Роджер Мур).

Comment: Спасибо. А можно ли, по вашему мнению, произносить с ударением на первый слог, как это случилось с Ньютоном (современные физики нередко говорят именно НьЮтон)?